# node.js Connect (not Express) hello-world example for session

Tags: node.js, everyauth

I need to implement [everyauth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth) with node.js Connect (not Express), very securely.

Despite the site provides some code samples for Connect, I'm not familiar with how node-Connect-session-middleware handles session.

Can someone please introduce some good simple examples to get start with?

PS. I found the official sample of Connect, but need a full working example.

http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you check out [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) (which I developed).  everyauth tends to make assumptions that Express is present, making integration into Connect-only apps difficult.

I developed Passport after wanting something more modular and easier to integrate.  It makes no assumptions, and is just simple middleware, so it drops in easily into Connect-based apps.

Comment: Jared, well, this looks exactly what I have been searching for. I really like your design concept, and actually found it's clear and easy integration to a connect-base project. I don't know how come I haven't hit your work until now, pity. Thanks a lot! I might be asking something during the development using your middleware. Great work, really. Thanks again.

Comment: @kenokabe Glad you like the project! Feel free to ping me with questions or feedback anytime.

Comment: I post a question on this theme, can you advise? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673337/node-jsconnectpassportpassport-google-oauth-error

Answer (score 0):

Express.js is actually a thin layer on top of Connect. So you could just use that as a reference and see how they do it.

Comment: After the question post, I have noticed what you say. I will investigate the Express sample more. Thank you, Pickels.